# Copy from Oracle to Vertica via CSV: lost rows

Tags: python, csv, vertica

I try to load data from Oracle to Vertica via CSV file

Used python,

wrote this script for create CSV from Oracle

```
csv_file = open("C:\DataBases\csv\%s_%s.csv" % (FILE_NAME, TABLE_NAME), "a", encoding = 'utf-8')
for row in cursor:
    count_rows += 1
result_inside = {}
row_content = []
for col, val in zip(col_names, row):
    result_inside[col] = val
row_content.append(result_inside[col])
result_select_from_oracle.append(result_inside)
file.write(json.dumps(result_inside,
    default = myconverter))
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ';', quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
writer.writerow(row_content)
```

wrote this script for COPY CSV to Vertica

```
connection = vertica_python.connect( * * conn_info)
cursor = connection.cursor()
with open("C:\DataBases\csv\%s_%s.csv" % (FILE_NAME, TABLE_NAME), "rb") as fs:
    record_terminator = '\n')
" %(SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME), my_file)
cursor.copy("COPY %s.%s from stdin PARSER fcsvparser(type='traditional', delimiter=';', record_terminator='\n')" % (SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME), my_file)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

After fineshed operation I had problem
from oracle 
Unloaded 40 000 rows
BUT in Vertica 39700 rows.

Where there can be a problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Try specifying REJECTED DATA and EXCEPTIONS clauses to see if some records were rejected.
Also, why are you using a flex parser? If anything, it's slow. The only cases where I use fcsvparser are either where the column order is unknown or values contain multi-line strings.

Comment: if I want to upload REJECTED DATA and EXCEPTIONS in file I must to write path file on vertica serter or I can write local path by windows server where I will try to run script? for example   FILE_NAME_REJECTED_DATE="C:\\DataBases\\csv\\rejected_date_%s.csv" % (TABLE_NAME) cursor.copy("COPY %s.%s FROM stdin DELIMITER as ';' rejected data '%s' " %(SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME, FILE_NAME_REJECTED_DATE), my_file)

Comment: it will save the files where you execute the script, which in this case means locally, rejected data file will be populated with the rows that was not copied and exceptions file will contain the reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COPY statement has two main stages: parsing and loading (there are other stages, but we’ll stick to these two). COPY rejects data only if it encounters problems during its parser phase. That’s when you end up with rejected data.

Potential causes for parsing errors include:

- Unsupported parser options
- Incorrect data types for the table into which data is being loaded
- Malformed context for the parser in use
- Missing delimiters

You may want the whole load to fail if even one row is rejected, for that, use the optional parameter ABORT ON ERROR

You may want to limit the number of rejected rows you’ll permit. Use REJECTMAX to set a threshold after which you want COPY to roll back the load process.

Vertica gives you these options to save rejected data:

- Do nothing. Vertica automatically saves a rejected data file and an
  accompanying explanation of each rejected row (the exception), to
  files in a catalog subdirectory called CopyErrorLogs.
- Specify file locations of your choice using the REJECTED DATA and
  EXCEPTIONS parameters (files will be saved on the machine which you run the script on) .
- Save rejected data to a table. Using a table lets you query what
  data was rejected, and why. You can then fix any incorrect data, and 
  reload it.

Vertica recommends saving rejected data to a table which will contain both the rejected data and the exception in one location. Saving rejected data to a table is simple, using the REJECTED DATA AS TABLE reject_table clause in the COPY statement

Comment: Returned exception Wrong number of columns! COPYing 99 columns from a source file containing: FEWER columns. BUT I verified rows not rejected and rejected row: counted same columns. What can be else?

Comment: do you have values which contain your delimiter ? try to change delimiter